# Xamarin Forms: Customising the InfoWindow

Tags: android, f#, xamarin.forms

I don't know if it's realistic to try to do this, but I'm attempting to customise my Xamarin Forms map by designing the InfoWindow (in the case of Android) or the callout (in the case of iOS) using Xamarin Forms.

My custom renderer in Android is as follows:

```
type GeographicMapRenderer() =
    inherit MapRenderer()
    let mutable formsMap = Unchecked.defaultof<DashboardMap>
    let mutable googleMap = Unchecked.defaultof<GoogleMap>
    let markerViewModel = new Dictionary<string, MarkerViewModel>()
    let subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable()
    let infoWindowClicked _ eventArgs = eventArgs |> ignore
    let infoWindowEventHandler = new EventHandler<Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs>(infoWindowClicked)
    override this.OnElementChanged e =
        base.OnElementChanged(e)
        match box e.OldElement with
        | null -> e |> ignore
        | _ -> googleMap.InfoWindowClick.RemoveHandler infoWindowEventHandler
        match box e.NewElement with
        | null -> e |> ignore
        | _ -> formsMap <- e.NewElement :?> DashboardMap; base.Control.GetMapAsync(this)
    override __.Dispose(disposing) = if disposing then subscriptions.Clear()
    interface IOnMapReadyCallback with 
        member this.OnMapReady map =
            googleMap <- map
            let pinsUpdated _ = 
                googleMap.Clear()
                markerViewModel.Clear()
                for pin in formsMap.PinnedLocations do 
                    let marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    match pin.ViewModel.Details with
                    | SearchResult _ -> marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueRed)) |> ignore
                    | PlaceOfInterest _ -> marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueAzure)) |> ignore
                    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Location.Latitude / 1.0<deg>, pin.Location.Longitude / 1.0<deg>)) |> ignore
                    googleMap.AddMarker marker |> fun m -> markerViewModel.[m.Id] <- pin.ViewModel
            formsMap.PinnedLocations.ItemsAdded.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(pinsUpdated) |> subscriptions.Add
            formsMap.PinnedLocations.ItemsRemoved.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(pinsUpdated) |> subscriptions.Add
            googleMap.InfoWindowClick.AddHandler infoWindowEventHandler
            googleMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter this
    interface Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter with
        member __.GetInfoContents(marker: Marker): Android.Views.View = Unchecked.defaultof<Android.Views.View>
        member __.GetInfoWindow(marker: Marker): Android.Views.View = 
            let view = markerViewModel.[marker.Id] |> ViewLocator.Current.ResolveView :?> Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement
            view.Parent <- formsMap
            let renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view)
            renderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout()
            let vg = renderer.ViewGroup
            vg :> Android.Views.View
    interface IJavaObject with member __.Handle = base.Handle
    interface IDisposable with member __.Dispose() = base.Dispose()
```

Note what happens in the `GetInfoWindow` method. The `ViewLocator` finds the Xamarin Forms view that contains the content that should be displayed in the InfoWindow. This has to be converted into an Android view, and for that purpose I use `Platform.GetRenderer()`. This gives the default renderer, which should render the view's children.

Unfortunately, the Android view that comes back has no child elements: it is just a large blue panel.

Do I need to write a custom renderer for the InfoWindow, or is there another crucial step I'm missing?